# Album art not displayed in music player in android

Tags: android, mediametadataretriever

I'm building a music player in Android. I'm displaying the album art for currently playing song. This is my code to retrieve the embedded image:-

```
public Bitmap getAlbumArt(String filePath) {
    Bitmap bm = null;

    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(filePath);
    byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

    // convert the byte array to a bitmap
    if(data != null) {
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    }

    return bm;
}
```

This code works fine and is able to retrieve album art but only for some songs. However, I can see the album art for all the songs in thumbnail view in Windows.

Could somebody explain what might be the reason behind this? Also, if there is an alternate way to achieve the same?

Thank You!